# Generate pagination links on twig view using illuminate pagination

Tags: twig, laravel-pagination

I'm having problem how can I able to generate links on twig view using the illuminate pagination. below is my codes.

Route:

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    $data = Todo::paginate(5);
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', [
        'title' => 'Home',
        'todolist' => $data,
    ]);
})->setName('homepage');
```

View:

```
{{todolist.links()}}
```

Error:

```
Call to a member function make() on null
```

btw I'm using Slim 3

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct methods to create the pagination? Have a look at [this](https://laravel.io/forum/11-13-2014-laravel-5-pagination) thread

Comment: here is my model @DarkBee
`<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "todo";
    protected $fillable = [
        'todo_name',
    ];
}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Raw statement is to print the output as plain html (not text)
Refer to this link https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html

```
{{todolist.links | raw}}
```

I tried on my slim 3 website and its works perfectly.

My Eloquent ver in the composer as below 
"illuminate/database": "^5.2", 
"illuminate/pagination": "~5.0"

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: I got this error `Call to a member function make() on null`

Comment: July, try check your Eloquent version

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel pagination & Blade templates.

Try this in your blade file:

```
{{ $todolist->links() }}
```

---

Laravel docs: [Displaying Pagination Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)